# Breakpoints for large screen mobile phones

Tags: css

I am using a mobile phone first approach in my CSS with a breakpoint of 980px for desktops/laptops. How do I tweak this code to ensure that large screen mobiles (such as the HTC with 1080 x 1920 resolutions) display the mobile phone design? Here is an example of my CSS. Thanks.

```css
div#navbar {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 980px) {
    div#navbar {display: inline;width: 100%;text-align: right;padding-right: 50px;padding-top: 0px;}
    div#navbar ul {list-style: none;margin:0px 0px 0px 50px; padding: 0;overflow: hidden;}
    div#navbar ul li {float: left;font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 20px;}
    div#navbar ul li a {padding: 0px 12px;color: #0d0d0d;text-transform: none;text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;}
    div#navbar ul li a:hover {text-decoration: none;color: #ffffff;text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #000000;}
    #content {margin-top:115px;}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just had a look at this table:

```
Device              Pixel Ratio
HTC Desire          1.5
HTC Desire HD       1.5
HTC Incredible S    1.5
HTC One X           2.0
```

So one way is you can use this `device-pixel-ratio` using:

```css
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

And target the mobile browsers. There are other things too, like `orientation`. These bits make sure that it targets **the mobile web browser**, and **not** the desktops or large screen projectors.

One example of this would be:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px and -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

The above works only for `HTC One X`.

Comment: The second example will not work with a site using the ideal viewport of the device (e.g. when using `<meta name="viewport" content="device-width...">` etc.).

Comment: @Emil Why do you say so? If so, how can we fix it?

Comment: Actually, it would still work—I sort of misread. But it's not because of the pixel ratio query: **the initial media query would still work too**. To explain: if TerryAlly was worried that his media query would be picked up by a high-res mobile browser, the answer is not to limit it to very high-res screens. As soon as the page is made responsive by adding the viewport meta, the viewport size is based on ideal viewport size, _not physical pixels_. See my answer for more details. HTC One has a physical width of 1080, but as far as CSS is concerned, it's 360, as the DPR is 3.

Comment: @Emil You know what? I tested it in the device and my two other devices and then only I posted this answer. `:)`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. The initial question was regarding how to change the query so that high-resolution mobile phones will show the mobile layout-not desktop. Which is a non-issue, as the width media query is not related to physical resolution, and would not be applied anyway. Your query added the proprietary -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio condition, but the query will still not apply, so there's no difference, right?

Comment: @Emil That's my answer.

Comment: To rephrase: your answer does not adress the original issue, and appears to misunderstand how media queries work in relation to mobile viewports. Hence the critique.

Comment: @Emil ha ha... Looks like we have a communication problem here... Lemme explain a bit..

Comment: @Emil Simple things: I agree with whatever you have said. What I am saying now is, the OP wants it for that *large screen mobiles* with `1080 x 1920` portrait orientation and it **shouldn't** work for the laptops, that have the same. Right? So when checking with the `device-pixel-ratio`, like you said, it is not the same for mobiles, if we target the `@media` query that way, it works for the mobiles and not for the laptops, right? Agree with my answer? Now what's the mistake? I am **ready to change my answer** accordingly.

Comment: OP asks how to make sure that his media query doesn't accidentally target mobile phones with high resolution. The styles _inside the media query_ are for desktop, the ones outside are for mobile. The physical resolution in question is irrelevant, as the media query will not target that value—the phone reports width of 360 _CSS pixels_ (according to [this table](http://www.mydevice.io/devices/)), providing viewport `<meta>` is correctly set. Your example will target devices reporting a _minimum_ of 980px wide + DPR of 2, so high-res large screen devices.

Comment: To quote your post, "These bits make sure that it targets the mobile web browser, and not the desktops or large screen projectors." — please remember that there are plenty of high-DPI laptops and desktops. Retina Macbooks, for example, will apply your media query. (Plus, your query has a syntax error in the media condition: should be `(min-width: 980px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)`). Finally, `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` is an older version of the syntax. Combine with `min-resolution: 2dppx` (or `192dpi` instead of `2dppx` if you want to get maximum backwards compat).

Comment: @Emil Awesome I learnt something new and great. Will update the answer after checking it. Thank you so much by the way... `:)`

Comment: @Emil and Praveen - my apology for confusing the device and CSS pixels. The CSS pixels are 360x640 while device pixels are 1080x1920 which Emil rightfully pointed out is irrelevant. I'm sorry for that confusion. The HTC One is not displaying correctly. Does it has anything to do with the device pixel ratio - 3.0 which I read at http://www.canbike.org/CSSpixels"?. Should I write a separate stylesheet for device pixel ratio 3.0 .... something like {@media screen and (max-width: 768px and -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)}?

Comment: @TerryAlly If you want to adapt the layouts for smaller screens, the DPR should be irrelevant, so it very much depends on what "not displaying correctly" means. Could you perhaps update your question with some more details, along with any viewport `<meta>`-tags you may be using?

Comment: @TerryAlly Your device pixel ratio must be **2**.

Comment: @Emil I've rechecked the display and it now all works correctly. Not sure why it was not before ... almost appears as though it was caching but all's well now. I've changed the breakpoint to min-width 1024px. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Praveen Kumar - all works well now. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @TerryAlly The nightmare of caching! LoL.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can keep the same media query independent of the *physical* screen resolution. You do *not* need to adapt dimensional media queries for high-resolution screens specifically, unless dealing with things like different images for different resolutions. I'll try to explain why.

### CSS pixels are not physical pixels.

The physical pixel resolution of the phone is basically irrelevant: what that media query responds to is *CSS pixels* which is a whole different thing.

There are two things to keep track of here:

- The "ideal viewport" size.
- Which viewport you are using.

The device will have an "ideal" viewport (from the browser's point of view) measured in pixels, often expressed as a multiple of the physical screen size.

For example: an old iPhone 3G has a device pixel ratio (DPR) of 1, and the screen is physically 320 pixels wide. The ideal viewport is then 320 pixels—meaning you can fit 320 pixels of content in.

A high end phone may have a 960 pixels wide screen, and a DPR of 3. Thus, its viewport is *still considered 320 pixels wide*, from the point of view of CSS and media queries. Most phones will end up with an ideal viewport somewhere in the 300–500 pixels range, in portrait mode.

### Use the ideal viewport.

**Note**: This depends on you actually *telling* the browser to use the ideal viewport — most often by using a meta tag like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`. If you don't, most mobile browsers will assume your site is not adapted for viewing on a small screen, and zoom out so that the viewport pretends to be a desktop-size browser (around 1000px wide or so). Your media queries will then respond to that fake size instead.

Here's a [very thorough presentation by PPK on the matter](http://quirksmode.org/presentations/Spring2014/viewports_jqueryeu.pdf).